# Django locale setting on Linux and Windows for number formatting

Tags: python, django, locale

I have a Django custom template tag

```
@register.filter("numformat")  
@stringfilter
def numformat(value, uLocale=''): 
    if uLocale.count('%') > 0 :
        return str((float(value)) *100) + "%"
    uLocale = uLocale.encode('utf8').strip("%")
    try :
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, uLocale)
    except :
        return str(locale.format('%f',float(value), True)) + ' Unknown loacale '+uLocale
        locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "")
    return str(locale.format('%f',float(value), True)) + ' in loacale '+uLocale
```

And it is called in the template file like

```
{% if val_i.NumberFormat %}
    {{ val_i.value|urldecode|numformat:val_i.NumberFormat }}
{% else %}
    {{ val_i.value|urldecode }}
{% endif %}
```

value of `val_i.NumberFormat` is :

- `deu_deu` in **Windows**
- `de_DE`in **Linux**

Issue is that code works only in **Windows** and not in **Linux**. Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using setlocale() this way might prove problematic, particularly because of threads (IIRC, setlocale() applies program-wide and should be called before spawning new threads). babel (http://babel.edgewall.org/) does what you are trying to achieve and works with Django.